# How to deserialize objects after closing an opening program in Java 11

Tags: java, object, serialization, loading

I have a program in which I am trying to implement saving and loading of obejcts, however I couldn't get the loading to work after the program closes, so effectively only saving and loading works while the program is open, but no data is ever loaded once the program starts. I assume this is something to do with overwiting. I created a test program to see if I could get it to work just using a simple Person class. I store my Peson objects inside an ArrayList and serialize it, then deserialize it. Currently I am storing all loaded Person objects in a JComboBox. I have looked online and could not find anything that will help. Also note I am aware that using serialization is not the best method of saving objects, but it's something suitable to use for my program.

**My App Class:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class App  extends JFrame {
    public static JComboBox<Person> peopleBox;
    public App(){
        try {
            Person.peopleList = loadList();
        }
        catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            saveList(Person.peopleList);
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        peopleBox = new JComboBox<>();
        peopleBox.setModel(getComboBoxModel(Person.peopleList));
        add(peopleBox);
        pack();
        setSize(600, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public DefaultComboBoxModel<Person> getComboBoxModel(ArrayList<Person> peopleList){
        Person[] comboBoxModel = peopleList.toArray(new Person[0]);
        return new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(comboBoxModel);
    }
    public static void saveList(ArrayList<Person> peopleList) throws IOException {
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.bin"));
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(peopleList);
    }
    public static ArrayList<Person> loadList() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("test.bin"));
        Person.peopleList = (ArrayList<Person>) objectInputStream.readObject();
        return  Person.peopleList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
       // Person p  = new Person("Sean", 22);
        try {
            saveList(Person.peopleList);
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        App app = new App();
        app.pack();
        app.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**Person Class**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Person implements Serializable {

    public int age;
    public String name;
    public static ArrayList<Person> peopleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Person(String name, int age){
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        peopleList.add(this);
        for(Person p : peopleList){
            System.out.println(p.toString());
        }
    }

    public Person(){
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Name : " + name + " Age: " + age;
    }
}
```

I expect when I save the list to the "test.bin" file, close the program, then open it again that it will load the list and display the Objects I created before I closed the program. I appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving an empty list before you load Person from the file.
I suggest this approach:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class App extends JFrame {

    public static JComboBox<Person> peopleBox;

    public App() {
        try {
            loadList();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            saveList(Person.peopleList);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        setSize(600, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void updateData(){
        peopleBox = new JComboBox<>();
        peopleBox.setModel(getComboBoxModel(Person.peopleList));
        add(peopleBox);
        pack();
    }

    public DefaultComboBoxModel<Person> getComboBoxModel(ArrayList<Person> peopleList) {
        Person[] comboBoxModel = peopleList.toArray(new Person[0]);
        return new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(comboBoxModel);
    }

    public static void saveList(ArrayList<Person> peopleList) throws IOException {
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.bin"));
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(peopleList);
    }

    public static void loadList() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("test.bin"));
        Person.peopleList.addAll((List<Person>) objectInputStream.readObject());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        Person p = new Person("Sean2", 24);
        try {
            saveList(Person.peopleList);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        app.updateData();
        app.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```